# Multiple Redirects based off Dropdown Answers in Form

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to find an answer to this and have tried a few things, but I'm hoping someone can help me out. I have a form on a Landing Page that redirects a submission to a disqualifying thank you page if the lead answers one of the questions incorrectly. I know the code I have works well in most cases but one of the questions has multiple answers that would disqualify a lead and it will only disqualify if they choose one option but not the other option that would ALSO disqualify that person.

For example, we have a dropdown selection that lets you choose your age range. If you choose "30-49" it needs to disqualify that person, which it does currently but I also need it to disqualify someone for choosing "65 and over" as well. Right now it will redirect to our disqualifying page if they choose "30-49" but it won't redirect if they choose "65 and over". I need it to do both.

I've tried adding the AND&& tag in my code instead of the OR|| tag but I'm still struggling to get it to work. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
<script> 
  
  function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

  
  var months_12 = getUrlVars()["months_12"];
  var doctor_care = getUrlVars()["doctor_care"];
  var current_benefits = getUrlVars()["current_benefits"];
  var have_attorney = getUrlVars()["have_attorney"];
  var first_name = getUrlVars()["first_name"];
  var last_name = getUrlVars()["last_name"];
  var age = getUrlVars()["age"];
  var email = getUrlVars()["email"];
  var phone_number = getUrlVars()["phone_number"];
  
  var redirect_url = '';
  if (months_12 == "No" || doctor_care == "No" || current_benefits == "Yes" || have_attorney == "Yes" || age == "30-49" || age == "65 and over") {
    redirect_url = "http://unbouncepages.com/mblsdd-thank-you-3/?"; 
  } 
  else {
    redirect_url = "http://unbouncepages.com/mblssd-thank-you-5/?";
  }
 
  redirect_url = redirect_url+"months_12="+months_12+"&doctor_care="+doctor_care+"&current_benefits="+current_benefits+"&have_attorney="+have_attorney+"&age="+age+"&first_name="+first_name+"&last_name="+last_name+"&email="+email+"&phone_number="+phone_number;
  
  window.location.href = redirect_url;


  
</script>
```

Comment: You have a 'redirect_url=' after the if/else statement.  So that means whatever the if/else comes up with it will be over written on the next line.  Maybe move it before the if/else.  That way only the if/else statement can change it.

Comment: Hey Charles, thanks for the reply! I gave that a try based on your suggestion but I'm still running into the same issue unfortunately. Any other ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ok, I see what you are doing.  You are adding a query string to the 'redirect_url' with that final 'redirect_url=redirect_url...' statement.  So that line must stay where it is.  The only other thing I can think of is for you to check the HTML for the '65 and over' option.  Maybe there is a space where it shouldn't be?

Comment: Yeah, you're correct in regards to the 'redirect_url' and I didn't see any formatting issues with '65 and over'. It's strange because I think my issue is happening somewhere in this string: age == "30-49" || age == "65 and over".

Comment: Can you console.log() each of variables to see what's in them?  I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: One more thing I just thought of.  Since you are getting the age variable from the query string has it been urlencoded?  Spaces aren't allowed in a query string and you encodeURI() them to replace some characters which includes the space character with %20 or maybe a +.  Maybe you can try to decodeURI() the variable?

Comment: If you console.log(age) and see a %20 or + where the space should be then you need to decodeURI() that variable.  To be safe you should decode each query string variable as you get the value.  And you should encode each variable when you place it in the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query strings in most modern browsers will automatically be encodeURI()'ed.  This means you must decodeURI() the query string value.  Also, you don't need to call the queryString() function for each key/value pair you need.  Ex:

```
function queryString()
{
 let vars = {};
 let parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value)
 {
  vars[key] = decodeURI(value);
 });
 return vars;
}


 const queryArray = queryString();
 let months_12 = queryArray["months_12"];
 let doctor_care = queryArray["doctor_care"];
 let current_benefits = queryArray["current_benefits"];
 let have_attorney = queryArray["have_attorney"];
 let first_name = queryArray["first_name"];
 let last_name = queryArray["last_name"];
 let age = queryArray["age"];
 let email = queryArray["email"];
 let phone_number = queryArray["phone_number"];

 let redirect_url = "";
 if(months_12 == "No" || doctor_care == "No" || current_benefits == "Yes" || have_attorney == "Yes" || age == "30-49" || age == "65 and over") {
   redirect_url = "http://unbouncepages.com/mblsdd-thank-you-3/?"; 
 } 
 else {
   redirect_url = "http://unbouncepages.com/mblssd-thank-you-5/?";
 }

 redirect_url = redirect_url+"months_12="+months_12+"&doctor_care="+doctor_care+"&current_benefits="+current_benefits+"&have_attorney="+have_attorney+"&age="+age+"&first_name="+first_name+"&last_name="+last_name+"&email="+email+"&phone_number="+phone_number;
  
 window.location.href = redirect_url;
```

If you try to get the value of a non-exsistant key then you will get 'undefined'.

Comment: This worked! Oh man that's quite a relief. Thank you for all your help with this, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  I don't use query strings that much so it took my brain a while to click about the encoding.  Since this fixed your problem can you please accept it as the answer and mark it?

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks again Charles, you're a legend!